# How to add tridion user using anguilla framework?

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I am trying to create new tridion user using Anguilla framework. I tried, but the user is not getting saved. When I'm saving the user, it's saying "cannot save item; paramer s is null".
Below is my code :

```
var newuser = $models.createNewItem($const.ItemType.USER);
newuser.setTitle("Test Title");
newuser.setDescription("Test description");
newuser.Privileges(1);
newuser.save(true);
```

I am getting an error saying "cannot save item; paramer s is null". But I'm struggling to find out which parameter I missed out. 
Can someone please guide me how to do that? If it is because I'm not setting the Membership of the user, can someone tell me how to set the membership of a user?

Comment: Abu, I am not a Anguilla expert so could be difficult to help you with the code. But Peter has developed a pretty cool Alchemy Plugin for it, it could be useful for you. http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/56619c3be4de021388dc465d

Comment: Priviledges seems to be misspelled; should be Privileges

Comment: Corrected, but in my code the spelling is correct

Answer (score -1):

Can you try it with a valid domain and username in your code? something like below:

```
newuser.setTitle("MyDomain\MyUserName");
```

Comment: I am passing valid user name only, I have replaced the actual values with dummy strings in the code which I pasted here.